# Only homepage working correctly, 404 error on everything else

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, rewrite-rules, homepage, mod-rewrite

I've been developing wordpress based websites for some time now, and i built one for my company's own brand, it worked with no problem at all for ages, but now for some reason, i can only get the homepage properly, for startesr, this is my setup:

1. Wordpress freshly updated to 3.7.1 (although problem existed before update and i hoped the update would fix whatever was causing before i had a clue of what's going on)
2. Gantry Framework and Theme updated to the most recent
3. Several plugins, not worth enumerating because it shouldnt be a plugin problem, i tried deactivating every single one and it returned nothing new.
4. NO ACCESS TO .htaccess !!! (this is where i think the problem lies...)

I believe im getting a permalink error, and i've been seeing everywhere on the internet i whould go to the permalink page and just save without making changes to flush the rewrite engine rules (sorry if this is not said the right way, im new to it), the problem is my host is not accepting my request for permissions to change the .htaccess files, for security reasons, they say... is there any way i can achieve this flush without having permissions to write on .htaccess? i have sent them the rules wordpress tells me to write on .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But after writing these, nothing changes, i still dont know what happened, i dont know if they changed something server-side (probably they changed permissions, because i had no problems before some weeks ago)...

Is there anyway to solve this problem on my side or do i have to just keep nagging the guys at the hosting company until they give me permission to write on .htaccess? What valid arguments could i point to them so they dont find me a threat to their servers?

Thank you for your time and answers :)

Comment: Can you access `.htaccess` over (s)FTP?

Comment: no man, access blocked by the host, i can see the file, i can download it, but when it uploads, gives me a permission error... Thank you for the answer, sorry for the time it took me to answer back, i was working on something else

Comment: Get a new host. I can understand not allowing the server to write the file, but blocking FTP is excessive.

Comment: i got them to give me access actually, and now the website is working just fine, thank you for your help anyway :)